# Error :Uncaught TypeError: Object function

Tags: javascript, methods

When I write `book.main.method();` I got error **:Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {**

```
window.book = window.book|| {};

    book.control = function() {
        var check_is_ready = 'check_is_ready';
        if(check_is_ready == 'check_is_ready') {
            this.startbook = function() {
                var bookMain = new book.main();
                    bookMain.method();
            return;
            };
        };
    };

$(function() {
    var control = new book.control();
    control.startbook();
});

(function () {
    book.main = function() {     
    var index =0;
        this.method = function() {
            index++;
            if (index <= 500){
                book.main.method();//  <-- this wrong
                // the error which I get :Uncaught TypeError: Object function () { 
                alert (index);
                }
         };
    };
})();
```

What should I write instead `book.main.method();` to invoke it with out error?

many thanks

Comment: I think this may be an improvement on your code at the moment, doesnt fix your issue though im afraid. http://pastebin.com/6pvmdBKp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly the main problematic code is:

```
(function () {
    book.main = function() {     
    var index =0;
        this.method = function() {
            index++;
            if (index <= 500){
                book.main.method();//  <-- this wrong
                // the error which I get :Uncaught TypeError: Object function () { 
                alert (index);
            }
         };
    };
})();
```

You are trying to call the `method()` recursively. Another way to do the recursive call is to give a name to the function expression (`methodFn`). Just remember that this name is only valid inside that function's body:

```
(function () {
    book.main = function() {     
    var index =0;
        this.method = function methodFn() {
            index++;
            if (index <= 500){
                methodFn();
                alert (index);
            }
         };
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the constructor (`book.main`) and the instance.

`this.method = function() {` adds a function to the instance you get with `new book.main()`, not to `book.main`.

I'm not sure of your exact final goal but you should replace

```
book.main.method();//  <-- this wrong
```

with

```
this.method();//  <-- this works
```

Note also that if you want to see incremented values of the alert you must switch two lines :

```
(function () {
    book.main = function() {     
    var index =0;
    this.method = function() {
        index++;
        if (index <= 2){
            console.log(index); // less painful with console.log than with alert
            this.method();
        }
     };
    };
})();
```

Comment: I write your line before and I got the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'method' `

Comment: See http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/14192384.263525.html . I replaced 500 with 2.